# Why it is not a tail recursion?

Tags: recursion, kotlin, functional-programming

I have the following code, that I do not understand, why it is not a tail recursion:

```
override fun drop(n: Int): List<A> = if (n == 0) this else tail.drop(n - 1)
```

whereas this is a tail recursion:

```
fun drop(n: Int): List<A> {
  tailrec fun drop(n: Int, list: List<A>): List<A> =
    if (n <= 0) list else when (list) {
      is Cons -> drop(n - 1, list.tail)
      is Nil -> list
    }
  return drop(n, this)
}
```

Why is the first example not a tail recursion?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think tail calls must be on the same object. So `tail.drop(n - 1)` is not a tail call because it's called on `tail`, not `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't tail recursion because Kotlin checks the recursive call is on the same receiver. In your case it's correct; `drop` is a virtual function (since you use `override`), so `tail.drop` could have a different implementation. For non-`open` functions there is the issue [Tailrec optimization not being applied to tail recursive calls on a non-this receiver](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26038), but it doesn't seem to be actively worked on.

Note this bug as well: [Recursive calls to open tailrec functions are generated incorrectly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18533)